# Python Find Type of extension in current directory, count them and find min, average, and max file size of each type of extension

Tags: python, directory

```
SplitTypes=[]
for file in os.listdir(os.curdir):
    SplitTypes.append(file.split('.')[-1])
collections.Counter(SplitTypes)
```

This gives me:

```
Counter({'txt': 2,
     'ipynb': 38,
     'Practical_Statistics': 1,
     'DS_Store': 1,
     'xlsx': 10,
     'xls': 2,
     'json': 9,
     'csv': 3,
     'workspace 2': 1,
     'py': 2,
     'templates': 1,
     'ipynb_checkpoints': 1,
     'log': 1,
     'exec -l ': 1})
```

but I would like to add, minumum, average, and max file size for each type of extension to that, as a list or dictionary doesnt matter. I know how to get each individual file size in my directory using:

```
for file in os.listdir(os.curdir):
    print(file, os.path.getsize(file))
```

but not sure how to aggregate based on extension type

Comment: um.. use a `for` loop? You already had a `Counter` object with all the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) will only give you back the counts, perhaps a file grouping approach might be more straightforward.

What you can do:

**1.** Group file sizes by extension, perhaps with a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

**2.** Perform statistics on each group of file sizes.

**Demo:**

```
from os import curdir
from os import listdir

from os.path import getsize
from os.path import splitext

from collections import defaultdict

# 1
d = defaultdict(list)
for file in listdir(curdir):
    _, extension = splitext(file)
    d[extension].append(getsize(file))

# 2
for extension, file_sizes in d.items():
    print('extension:', extension)
    print('count:', len(file_sizes))
    print('min file size:', min(file_sizes))
    print('max file size:', max(file_sizes))
    print('average file size:', sum(file_sizes) / len(file_sizes))
```